# Bar Graph Index Label

Tags: javascript

I need to show index label for bar graph

Here is the code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "hideCredits":true,
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "Status": "Completed",
    "visits": Total
  }, {
    "Status": "On-Going",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "Status": "Procurement",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "Status": "DED Prep",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "Status": "Under Prep",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "Status": "Suspended",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "Status": "No Status Yet",
    "visits": 711
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  } ],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "Status",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

} );
```

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions. Usually there's some problem, a paragraph of what you tried and an `?` involved. Read [ask], take a [tour]

Comment: And please don't use bold shouty text when it is unnecessary.

Comment: sorry newbee here

Comment: Please can you give more details of the problem.

I put your code in codepen.
The only change I made was to add var Total=0;

https://codepen.io/newschapmj1/pen/vjqpKL

Comment: @johnc i want to show index label or the value on top or end of the bar

Comment: There was a warning shown you when you posted your question for the first time, what was the warning text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this](https://codepen.io/newschapmj1/pen/WJqdqa)?

I added these 2 lines to the graphs section

```
 "labelText": "[[visits]]",
 "labelPosition": "top"
```

Comment: i think this is it, thank you soo much!